# Dockerized .NET6 application throws Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904) error

Tags: docker, azure-sql-database, .net-6.0

I have a .net6 application that used uses Azure Sql server.  The application works fine on .Net3.1 but when ported to .Net6 the application throw a Sql server error

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The instance of
> SQL Se rver you attempted to connect to requires encryption but this
> machine does not s upport it

The dockerfile is very generic and look like below

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Presentation/Web.Cms/Web.Cms.csproj", "Presentation/Web.Cms/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Presentation\Web.Cms\Web.Cms.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Presentation/Web.Cms"
RUN dotnet build "Web.Cms.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Web.Cms.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Web.Cms.dll"]
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
USER ContainerAdministrator
```

Comment: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient v2 and later uses encryption by *default*. Did your older project use an old SqlClient version, one that didn't use encryption? What's the *full* exception text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient v2.0 and later use encryption by default if the server supports it.

This will cause problems if the server uses a certificate that isn't trusted by the server. In that case the exception will include a message (either directly or in an inner exception) saying that the server certificate isn't trusted. In this case you can add `TrustServerCertificate=true` to the connection string.

Another problem specific to containers is described in [Unable to open connection to azure sql database from windows1809 container with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 2.0.0](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/714): the container image may not have the `Security.dll` in `C:\Windows\System32`. In that issue the Nano image was used.

There's a relevant issue in the [Windows Containers repo](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Containers/issues/134). It seems that at least the .NET 5 runtime base image doesn't have `Security.dll`.

One of the workarounds mentioned in the SqlClient issue is to copy the file there. Some of the comments in the linked issue show how to do this.

From the command line

```
docker cp C:\Windows\System32\security.dll container-name:/Windows/System32/security.dll
```

Or in the docker file

```
COPY --from=core /Windows/System32/security.dll /Windows/System32/security.dll
```

Another is to enable [Managed networking on Windows](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/2c2f100d8ab9a1f6ee8c048a260d77e6a738e1e7/release-notes/2.0/2.0.0.md#enable-managed-networking-on-windows) which also removes the need for the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI binaries. To enable this set the following switch at startup :

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.UseManagedNetworkingOnWindows", true);
```

The downside mentioned in the article is that

> Managed SNI does not support non-domain Windows Authentication.